# Result of a soql parent to child soql request

Tags: json, salesforce, soql

I would to know how I can display the result from a soql child to parent request.

```
$query = "SELECT FirstName, LastName, (select Retreat_Booking__c.Retreat__c from Retreat_Bookings__r)FROM Contact" 

$response = $mySforceConnection->query($query);   
$queryResult = new QueryResult($response);  
while($queryResult->current()->FirstName!='' || $queryResult->current()->LastName!='')
{
    echo $queryResult->current()->FirstName." ".$queryResult->current()->LastName." ".$queryResult->current()->Retreat__c." <BR/>";
    $queryResult->next();
}
```

The request works and display "FirstName" and "LastName" but not "Retreat__c".
I know the result in the 2nd select is a json and I tried many things, but nothing works.

Comment: don't you need to alias that last column in your SQL to give it an actual name? Otherwise how would the calling code (PHP I guess? You didn't say) know how to reference the column? Retreat__c is only a valid name within the subquery, not the main output.

Comment: Try `$query = "SELECT FirstName, LastName, (select Retreat_Booking__c.Retreat__c from Retreat_Bookings__r) as Retreat__c FROM Contact"` . I don't know soql specifically but that's the standard SQL way of doing it.

Comment: Not sure about which php library you are using  but wouldn't it be $queryResult->current()-> Retreat_Bookings__r->Retreat_Booking__c->Retreat__c

Comment: Thanks Adyson, sorry, yes it's php, but the database is saleforce, and there are no alias in soql.

Comment: To G Jordan, thanks, but not, doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Query should be like below

```
$query = "SELECT FirstName, LastName, (select Retreat_Booking__r.Retreat__c from Retreat_Bookings__c)FROM Contact";
```

That is,

`Retreat_Booking__r.Retreat__c` instead of `Retreat_Booking__c.Retreat__c`

and

`from Retreat_Bookings__c` instead of `Retreat_Bookings__r`

After `FROM` there should be the custom object name which is (extension is `__c`) `Retreat_Bookings__c` and retrieving data from a reference objects field, you should use `__r` extension and thus `Retreat_Booking__r.Retreat__c`

**Update**

For your 2nd question, you can try

```
$query = "SELECT FirstName, LastName, (select Retreat_Booking__r.Retreat__c from Retreat_Bookings__c) AS rb FROM Contact"
```

and then

```
while($queryResult->current()->FirstName!='' || `$queryResult->current()->LastName!='')
{
echo $queryResult->current()->FirstName." ".$queryResult->current()->LastName." ".$queryResult->current()->rb.Retreat__c" <BR/>";
$queryResult->next();
}`
```

Comment: Hi Noor A Shuvo, very thank's to try to find a solution, unfortunately alias doesn't work in salesforce.